# How to use ZLIB deflate method?

Tags: compression, zlib

I am trying to use zlib to compress a text file. It seems to kinda work except I pretty sure my calculation of the number of bytes to write to the output is wrong.  My code (guided by http://zlib.net/zlib_how.html) is below:

```
int
deflateFile(
  char *infile,
  char *outfile)
{
    #define CHUNKSIZE 1000
    int n,nr,nw,towrite;
    z_stream strm;
    FILE *fin,*fout;
    BYTE *inbuf,*outbuf;
    int ntot=0;

    printf( "Start doDeflateFile:\n" );

    // ALLOC BUFFERS
    inbuf  = malloc( CHUNKSIZE+1 );
    outbuf = malloc( CHUNKSIZE+1 );

    // OPEN FILES
    fin  = fopen( infile,  "rb" );
    fout = fopen( outfile, "wb" );
    
    // SETUP Z STREAM
    strm.zalloc    = Z_NULL;
    strm.zfree     = Z_NULL;
    strm.opaque    = Z_NULL;    
    strm.avail_in  = CHUNKSIZE; // size of input
    strm.next_in   = inbuf;     // input buffer
    strm.avail_out = CHUNKSIZE; // size of output
    strm.next_out  = outbuf;    // output buffer
    
    deflateInit( &strm, Z_BEST_COMPRESSION );   // init stream level
      
    while( TRUE ) {         // loop til EOF on input file
      // READ NEXT INPUT CHUNK
      nr = fread( inbuf, 1, CHUNKSIZE, fin );
      if( nr <= 0 ) {
        printf( "End of input\n" );
        break;
      }
      printf( "\nread  chunk of  %6d bytes\n", nr );

      printf( "calling deflate...\n" );
      n = deflate(&strm, Z_FINISH);             // call ZLIB deflate

      towrite = CHUNKSIZE - strm.avail_out;     // calc # bytes to write (FIXME???)
      printf( "#bytes to write %6d bytes\n", towrite );
      nw = fwrite( outbuf, 1, towrite, fout );
      if( nw != towrite ) break;
      printf( "wrote chunk of  %6d bytes\n", nw );
      ntot += nw;
    }
        
    deflateEnd(&strm);              // end deflate

    printf( "wrote total of %d bytes\n", ntot );
    printf( "End deflateFile.\n" );

    return( 0 );
}
```

The output for a 1010-byte input file with a CHUNKSIZE of 1000 is:

```
 Start deflateFile:

read  chunk of    1000 bytes
calling deflate...
#bytes to write    200 bytes
wrote chunk of     200 bytes

read  chunk of      10 bytes
calling deflate...
#bytes to write    200 bytes
wrote chunk of     200 bytes
End of input
wrote total of 400 bytes

End deflateFile.
```

SO #4538586 sort of addressed this but not quite and it's very old..
*Can anybody point out my problem?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read that page again. Much more carefully this time.

You are not setting `avail_in` properly at the start, and you are not resetting `next_in`, `avail_in`, `next_out`, and `avail_out` in the loop. The only thing you are doing correctly is the thing you think is wrong, which is the calculation of how many bytes to write out. What you have will not even "kinda work".

First off, `avail_in` must always be set to the amount of available input at `next_in`. Hence the name `avail_in`. You are setting it to `CHUNKSIZE` and calling `inflateInit()`, even though there is *no available input* in that buffer yet.

Then after you read data into the input buffer, you ignore `nr`! You need to set `avail_in` to `nr`, to indicate how much data is *actually* in the buffer. It might be less than `CHUNKSIZE`.

You should read data into the input buffer *only* if you have processed all of the data that was there from the last read, indicated by `avail_in` being zero.

When a call of `deflate()` completes inside the loop, it has updated `next_in`, `avail_in`, `next_out`, and `avail_out`. To use the `inbuf` and `outbuf` buffers again, you need reset the values of `next_in`, `next_out`, and `avail_out` to the values you did initially. `avail_in` will be set at the top of the loop from `nr`.

You are calling `deflate()` with `Z_FINISH` every time! The way this works is that you call `deflate()` with `Z_NO_FLUSH` until the last of the input is provided, and *then* you use `Z_FINISH`, to let it know to finish. (That's why it's called that.)

Your loop will exit prematurely, since you need to finish compressing and writing the output, not just finish reading the input.

You are not checking the return code of `deflate()`. *Always* check return codes. That's why they're there.

Good luck.

Comment: I read the doc until my eyes bled but I just couldn't get it. But thanks to your excellent and clear suggestions I got it working. I'll post my corrected code after I clean it up.